# Loopback: Error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

Can any one tell me why this issue is occur while running the loopback.

```
Error: Cannot PROPFIND /webdav/
at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:15:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at serveStatic (/usr/lib/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:74:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/developer/myapps-angularjs/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
```

Is this error will affect other document API's?
Is this the major error?

Answer (score 1):

`raiseUrlNotFoundError` occurs when the endpoint called doesn't exists. If you are using Angular SDK fro loopback, check the urlBase parameter in lb-services.js file.